# redirecting daemon output when already redirected to /dev/null

Tags: c, linux, daemon, io-redirection

I have created a program that has the option to be started as a daemon, as well as the option to redirect output to a file. Everything works as expected unless the application is started with it's output already directed to /dev/null.  This is a problem because the application is being started by another application where the output is redirected to /dev/null.

Starting the application like this will work as expected, with all output written to the file.

```
./my_daemon -d -f/tmp/logfile
```

However, starting the application like this will create the log file, but it will be empty.

```
./my_daemon -d -f/tmp/logfile &> /dev/null
```

The program is:

```
sintn main(sintn osn_argc, charn *opacn_argv[])
{
  sintn sn_i;
  charn *pcn_log_file = NULL;
  boolean q_daemonize;
  sintn sn_log_file = -1;
  pid_t t_pid = 0;
  pid_t t_sid = 0;

  printf("Enter Main\n");

  //check for parameters
  for (sn_i = 1; sn_i < osn_argc; sn_i++)
  {
     if (opacn_argv[sn_i][0] == '-')
     {
        switch(opacn_argv[sn_i][1])
        {
           case 'd':
           case 'D':
              q_daemonize = TRUE;
              break;

           case 'f':
           case 'F':
              pcn_log_file = &opacn_argv[sn_i][2];
              break;

           default:
              printf("Unknown parameter '%s'\n", opacn_argv[sn_i]);
        }
     }
  }

  if (q_daemonize == TRUE)
  {
     t_pid = fork();// fork a new child process

     if (t_pid < 0)
     {
        printf("Fork failed!\n");
        exit(1);
     }

     if (t_pid > 0)// its the parent process
     {
        printf("Forked: pid of child process %d \n", t_pid);
        exit(0); //terminate the parent process succesfully
     }

     umask(0);//unmasking the file mode

     t_sid = setsid();//set new session
     if(t_sid < 0)
     {
        exit(1);
     }

     close(STDIN_FILENO);

     if (pcn_log_file != NULL)
     {
        sn_log_file = open(pcn_log_file, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO );
     }

     if (sn_log_file >= 0)
     {
        dup2(sn_log_file, STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(sn_log_file, STDERR_FILENO);
     }
     else
     {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);
     }
  }


  printf("Starting Application\n");
  v_BRIDGE_process();
  printf("Application Exit\n");

  printf("Exit Main\n");

  if (q_daemonize == TRUE)
  {
     if (sn_log_file >= 0)
     {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);
        close(sn_log_file);
     }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I suppose the obvious answer of "don't do that" is not altogether helpful, but still, if the program's `-f` option is supposed to direct output to a file instead of to `stdout`, then also performing a separate redirection via the shell is at best inconsistent.

Comment: It is strange that when you daemonize but do not (successfully) direct the output and error streams to a file, you *close* the output and error streams.  That is unlikely to work out well when your program later tries to write to one or both of those streams.

Comment: It might be worthwhile checking the return values of your `dup2()` calls to verify that they are successful.

Comment: Although it is unlikely to be your issue, it is very strange to turn on execute permissions for a log file, and it is a security risk to allow "others" to write to such a file.

Comment: What happens if you start your program as `./my_daemon -d -f/tmp/logfile &> /tmp/otherfile`?  Which, if either, of the designated files receives the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After daemonizing and doing the `dup2` bit and setting up `stdout` and `stderr` correctly, you run into this bit of code:

```
if (q_daemonize == TRUE)
  {
     if (sn_log_file >= 0)
     {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);
        close(sn_log_file);
     }
  }
```

which promptly closes the file descriptors you've been so careful to attach to your log file with `dup2`.

I'm presuming the purpose here is clear-up. Firstly, you can just delete this, as a process exiting will clean up its own FDs. Secondly, this is causing a problem as your `printf` statement above will not have been flushed to the file descriptor for `stdout` as stdio is buffered. If you `fflush` stdout, it will probably work, but the better strategy is simply to exit and let `stdio`'s own exit handlers close the file.

Comment: I took out the code you mentioned, but it had no effect.  I agree that it is redundant, however, I wouldn't see where closing the file before the program exits would have any effect on the file flush.  Like I said, the file redirect works just fine as long as I don't start the daemon with stdout already redirected to /dev/null.

Comment: It appears that this was correct after all.  It wasn't that the redirect wasn't working, but that the files weren't being flushed when they were closed prematurely.  If there was a lot of output, it would still go to the file, some of it was just truncated.

I've modified the code to take into account all of the suggestions both here and above.